# How to transfer data in invoice to register payment in odoo v15?

Tags: python, odoo

I add fields in 'acoount_move' and in 'account_register_payment' .

so, I want to show what is in the field 'acoount_move' in  the field 'account_register-payment'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [action_register_payment](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L3258) method

```
def action_register_payment(self):
    ''' Open the account.payment.register wizard to pay the selected journal entries.
    :return: An action opening the account.payment.register wizard.
    '''
    return {
        'name': _('Register Payment'),
        'res_model': 'account.payment.register',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'context': {
            'active_model': 'account.move',
            'active_ids': self.ids,
        },
        'target': 'new',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    }
```

Pass the field value in the context and prefix the field name with `default_` so the field in the payment register wizard will be automatically set for you.

In the following example, we suppose you have a reference (char field) in the account move model and you want to pass its value to the payment wizard, we take into consideration that the `action_register_payment` method is multi-record (self could be a recordset with multiple account moves)

***Example:***

```
def action_register_payment(self):
    res = super(AccountMove, self).action_register_payment()
    res['context']['default_reference'] = ', '.join(rec.reference for rec in self)
    return res
```